# How do I use the clock on my Ilve oven?

Tags: equipment, oven

I recently bought an Ilve oven second-hand.  I can't figure out how to use the clock/timer functions.

The oven is 10-15 years old, and all the manuals I have found are for newer/different ovens.

Can anyone explain how to set the time and use the timer functions?  What do the 6 settings on the clock dial mean?

Below is a picture of the clock, there is a full picture of the oven itself [here](http://cgi.ebay.com.au/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=250745592618&ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have had a lot of success asking questions of the Repair Guru at Repair Clinic (I am not affiliated in any way except as a satisfied customer).  You email them a question and within a day or two they get back to you with an answer.  Not all of my questions were obviously going to lead to me purchasing any parts, but they were very helpful anyway.  They may or may not have your manual available (a quick search of their site didn't reveal anything by Ilve, but I'm willing to bet they could help.

To ask a question, click [this link](http://www.repairclinic.com/Repair-Help) and in the upper right, click **one-to-one Repair Guru emails** in the blue circle.

You have to register, but it's only so they can assign you a case and you can easily get back to it.  I use *name+company@gmail.com* formatting with my gmail address and no spam originated from them when I signed up a couple years ago.

Answer (score 0):

http://ilve.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/24-Oven-Operating-Recipe-Manual-2013-V1-low-res.pdf

something similar i`ve find here

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.